# PCI scope for credit card forms that talk to Stripe, Braintree, etc

Tags: pci-dss

I client of mine is using a custom credit card form, which talks to Stripe, Braintree, etc

To make this acceptable for a PCI audit, currently they do the following:

- 1. They host the files in a separate repo + deploy train
- 2. They expose the form via an iframe, which is talked too via window.postMessage

Now the problem:

From a developer and product perspective this is unideal. They now need to manage a separate deploy train, and the code is more susceptible to bugginess (making an iframe appear seamless is tough).

My initial assumption was:

- Why can't we just host it in the same deploy train + same repo, and have custom git rules on who can edit those files?

  - The response was:

    - Technically, any js on the same page could use the DOM to access that information, which means everything would have to be under PCI scope
    - Hence they had to have separate deploy + iframe to avoid this.

From research I *think* having our own form inputs would make us SAQ A-EP

Question for you:

- What would the ramifications be for ditching the iframe?

  - Would we now need to make sure that the whole frontend repo is SAQ A-EP compatible?

    - i.e could we just PCI-scope those files, or is it a must to have an iframe?
    - What are the alternative options?

Comment: Try to be more specific. And try to avoid question like *What's the recommended way?* There is no **the** recommended way. The optimal solution in specific case depends on specific requirements in this case. What is good in one case is bad in another case.

Comment: Thanks @mentallurg -- will update the question

Comment: Note that a bunch of payment systems provide their own iFrame pre-existing libraries, so in many cases you already have "a separate repo" anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three FAQs on the PCI SSC website that will help you to answer this question.

https://pcissc.secure.force.com/faq/articles/Frequently_Asked_Question/Why-is-SAQ-A-EP-used-for-Direct-Post-while-SAQ-A-is-used-for-iFrame-or-URL-redirect

https://pcissc.secure.force.com/faq/articles/Frequently_Asked_Question/Why-is-there-a-different-approach-for-Direct-Post-implementations-than-for-iFrame-and-URL-redirect-what-are-the-technical-differences-and-how-do-they-impact-the-security-of-e-commerce-transactions

https://pcissc.secure.force.com/faq/articles/Frequently_Asked_Question/How-is-the-payment-page-determined-for-SAQ-A-merchants-using-iframe

And also a helpful guidance document "Best Practices in Securing eCommerce - 
https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/best_practices_securing_ecommerce.pdf

Simply it is harder for a criminal to attack an IFRAME'd payment page than it is to skim cardholder data out of the DOM if you host all the payment form fields yourself. Securing your website to A-EP is harder and will cost more than if you redirect or IFRAME. If that cost and risk is worth the benefit you’d get from hosting your own form fields then that's a reason to change. Personally unless your business is payment card data security, I'd always recommend giving the problem to someone else.